# How to set a single, main title above all the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am using `pyplot`. I have 4 subplots. How to set a single, main title above all the subplots? `title()` sets it above the last subplot.

Answer (score 466, accepted):

Use [`pyplot.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html?highlight=suptitle#matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle) or [`Figure.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=suptitle#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()
data=np.arange(900).reshape((30,30))
for i in range(1,5):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(2,2,i)        
    ax.imshow(data)

fig.suptitle('Main title') # or plt.suptitle('Main title')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Works with `suptitle`. Still, I saw your "shameless hack!" :)

Comment: Note, it is `plt.suptitle()` and not `plt.subtitle()`. I did not realize this in the beginning and got a nasty error! :D

Answer (score 209):

A few points I find useful when applying this to my own plots:

- I prefer the consistency of using `fig.suptitle(title)` rather than `plt.suptitle(title)`
- When using `fig.tight_layout()` the title must be shifted with `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.88)`
- See answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28132929/4013571) about fontsizes

Example code taken from [subplots demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) in matplotlib docs and adjusted with a master title.

[image: A nice 4x4 plot]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Simple data to display in various forms
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig.suptitle("This Main Title is Nicely Formatted", fontsize=16)

axarr[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axarr[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0] Subtitle')
axarr[0, 1].scatter(x, y)
axarr[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1] Subtitle')
axarr[1, 0].plot(x, y ** 2)
axarr[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1,0] Subtitle')
axarr[1, 1].scatter(x, y ** 2)
axarr[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1,1] Subtitle')

# # Fine-tune figure; hide x ticks for top plots and y ticks for right plots
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in axarr[0, :]], visible=False)
plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in axarr[:, 1]], visible=False)

# Tight layout often produces nice results
# but requires the title to be spaced accordingly
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.88)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Simply adding `figure.suptitle()` is not enough since titles of subplots will mix with suptitile, `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.88)` is good.

Answer (score 50):

If your subplots also have titles, you may need to adjust the main title size:

```
plt.suptitle("Main Title", size=16)
```

Comment: In python 2.7 it is **fontsize** instead of **size**. 
`plt.suptitle("Main Title", fontsize=16)`