# Matplotlib: center title relative to entire chart including axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, centering the title centers it relative to the main body of the chart.

Instead, I want to center it relative to the entire plot, including the y axis and the y axis label.

How can I do this? I'm assuming that at the very least I can manually define the exact horizontal position of the title, but I can't even figure out how to do that.

This generates a plot using title (in red) and supertitle (in blue). They're in slightly different positions, but they both appear to be centered relative to the main chart area of the text.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
volume = [2900, 1500, 2400, 1200]
d = pd.DataFrame({'Month': month, 'Volume': volume})
_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(ylabel='Volume (cbm)', xlabel='')
b = d.plot(kind='bar', y="Volume", x="Month", ax=ax)
plt.title('Title', color='red')
plt.suptitle('Title', color='blue')
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image: the output]

Comment: If you have a single subplot, use `plt.suptitle()` as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066121/how-to-set-a-single-main-title-above-all-the-subplots-with-pyplot). I would hence mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I've edited the question to show the result of using plt.suptitle(). It does move slightly, but still appears to be centered above the main body of the chart.

Comment: `plt.suptitle` puts the title in the middle of the figure. [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1vjN.png). Since you haven't shared all information to reproduce the issue, one cannot help here. If you have a problem, you may of course show a [mcve] of the issue which would allow to actually help you solve it.

Comment: Yes, that sloppy of me. I've rewritten the question with a code example. I can put images back in, but I'm not sure they help. Your example looks like it is doing what I want. Where is this example from? A reverse image search doesn't turn anything up, so I'm assuming you created it.

Comment: Yes, I created that image. But also your code does what you are asking. The blue title is **exctly** in the middle of the figure (letters start 203 pixels from the left and end 203 pixels from the right), and that is what the question asks for, right?

Comment: You're right. Not sure what I was thinking. Should I delete this non-question?

Comment: Since it is closed anyways and not really clear, you may indeed just delete it.